# Building a GUI in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sql

I’m planning on building some business processes that use SQL as the data source and allow SharePoint 2013 users to interact with the data. I’m not sure how to give the users a GUI inside SharePoint. I can use InfoPath, but that’s more for the data entry/collection etc. I can use an Access Web App, but there are too many drawbacks. Can’t trigger workflows, cant access already existing databases, etc. The dashboards, PowerView, etc. are for reports and displaying data, not data manipulation.

What exactly is the preferred method of creating a GUI inside SharePoint 2013 to allow this type of data interaction?

Comment: Have you thought about External Content Types and External Lists?

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting a new project, your best bet for forward compatibility is to develop it as an app - effectively, it'll be an asp.net application (or other web technology of your choice) that talks to SharePoint for one thing or other and has a few points that can be plugged in to SharePoint (App Parts) to consume/display the information.

You also have the alternative of creating External content types, which can be mappings of your tables into SharePoint. SharePoint will then generate the interfaces for you. Going with this, though, you might be locked out of the SPO market.